# Creating a generic typed member variable without type parameters specified on the class

Tags: c#, generics

I apologise for the unclear title, I don't really know how else to say it. I'll demonstrate with code.

```
public class CalculationService
{
    private static Calculator<StaticInstrument, StaticResult> _staticCalculator;
    private static Calculator<DynamicInstrument, DynamicResult> _dynamicCalculator;
    private static readonly object IsInitializedLock = new object();

    public byte[] ProcessStatic()
    {
        lock (IsInitializedLock)
        {
            _staticCalculator = new Calculator<StaticInstrument, StaticResult>();
        }

        return _staticCalculator.Calculate();
    }

    public byte[] ProcessDynamic()
    {
        lock (IsInitializedLock)
        {
            _dynamicCalculator = new Calculator<DynamicInstrument, DynamicResult>();
        }

        return _dynamicCalculator.Calculate();
    }
}
```

I have many methods that are identical, except for the fact that the type parameters of the Calculator objects are different.

The problem is, because `CalculationService` is a WCF service, it *cannot* have any type parameters. For this reason I can't simply create a static member `Calculator<TInstrument, TResult>`, because I cannot put type parameters on `CalculationService`.

My *ideal* solution would be something like this:

```
public class CalculationService
{
    private static Calculator<TInstrument, TResult> _calculator;
    private static readonly object IsInitializedLock = new object();

    public byte[] Process<TInstrument, TResult>()
    {
        lock (IsInitializedLock)
        {
            _calculator = new Calculator<TInstrument, TResult>();
        }

        return _calculator.Calculate();
    }

    public byte[] ProcessStatic()
    {
        return Process<StaticInstrument, StaticResult>();
    }

    public byte[] ProcessDynamic()
    {
        return Process<DynamicInstrument, DynamicResult>();
    }
}
```

But I can't create that `private static Calculator<TInstrument, TResult> _calculator` member without specifying type information on `CalculationService`, which I cannot do with WCF.

The only way I can think to do this would be to have

```
private static dynamic _calculator;
```

Is there any other way? I would rather avoid using dynamic if possible, I'm not sure what the performance implications could be, if any.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509803/naming-generic-datacontracts-in-wcf

Comment: Why don't just work with object and unbox the data on the client side, may be with a generic wrapper that works type safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand your later comment about having "just *one* instance of Calculator on my CalculationService class"; rather, it seems to me that you need one instance per <TInstrument,TResult>, as in the code you posted originally. I think the below code will do what you want (with the added bonus that the static initialization rules will thread-safely construct the Calculator at the right time).

```
public class CalculationService {
  private static class Inner<TInstrument, TResult> {
    public static readonly Calculator<TInstrument, TResult> _calculator;

    static Inner() {
      _calculator=new Calculator<TInstrument, TResult>();
    }
  }

 public byte[] ProcessStatic() {
    return Inner<StaticInstrument, StaticResult>._calculator.Calculate();
  }

  public byte[] ProcessDynamic() {
    return Inner<DynamicInstrument, DynamicResult>._calculator.Calculate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could "burn in" the types using inheritance to keep WCF from complaining.

```
public class StaticCalculator:Calculator<StaticInstrument, StaticResult> {}
public class DynamicCalculator:Calculator<DynamicInstrument, DynamicResult> {}

public class CalculationService
{
    private static StaticCalculator _staticCalculator;
    private static DynamicCalculator _dynamicCalculator;
    ...
```

I've done this before to work around WCF's lack of support for generic type parameters.

Comment: No, the problem is rather that I only want to have *one* instance of Calculator on my CalculationService class. The concrete generic types work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want 1 version of your service, you cannot have a single `_calculator` variable. The "easy" way is to use some version of a lookup structure (like dictionary, etc.) and lookup the proper calculator. Use the combination of `TInstrument` and `TResult` as the key to your calculator.

You can then use the `typeof` operator to get your keys. Something like:

```
_calculators = new Dictionary<Type,<Dictionary<Type,Calculator<TInstrument, TResult>>>();
...
var key1 = typeof(TInstrument);
var key2 = typeof(TResult);
var calculator = _calculators[key1].[key2];
...
```

I know this may seem complicated because of the generics syntax for creating a generic dictionary of dictionaries of calculators... but it works.

Hope this helps,

Eric.