# WCF: how to send various types of messages using one method

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, client-server

I'm new to WCF, and googled on that problem, but to no avail. I basically have WCF client/server application, using basicHttpBinding with HTTPS enabled  as a transport. What I would like is to be able to send various types of data (i.e. various messages) using just one generic method. 
I have my data defined like this in the WCF service:

```
[DataContract]
public class Payment
{
[DataMember]
int Pay_id
{
    get { return Payment_Id; }
    set { Payment_Id = value; }
}
[DataMember]
...
etc.
```

I will also have classes other than Payment, f.e. Config, Update, Log. Is it possible in WCF to write and use just one [Operation Contract] method to send any of these custom class objects? Like

```
SendMessage (Payment p); 
SendMessage (Config c);
```

Instead of writing new method for each new type of message, which is, I think, bad design choice (hard to extend)? As of now, it seems I can instantiate in WCF client proxy only types stated in the definition of [OperationContract] method, so if it's

```
SendMessage(GenericMessage message)
```

then I can't use

```
Payment payment = new Payment();
```

in the client, even if Payment is child class of GenericMessage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer:

[Naming Generic DataContracts in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509803/naming-generic-datacontracts-in-wcf)

Also if you have method like:

```
SendMessage(ParentClass object)
```

you can use child class objects:

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass
```

just add to your wcf client something like this:

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
      <declaredTypes>
        <add type="Your.Namespace.ParentClass, Your.Assembly">
          <knownType type="Your.Namespace.ChildClass, Your.Asembly"/>
        </add>
      </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
  </system.runtime.serialization>
```

Also, take a look at this article:

[All About KnownTypes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scenario where you have a base class (`GenericMessage` in your example) you simply need to use the [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute on your operation contract like so:

```
[OperationContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Payment))]
[KnownType(typeof(Config))]
SendMessage(GenericMessage message);
```

You can also specify the known types in the configuration if you prefer.  More information about that here:  [system.runtime.serialization config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967387.aspx).

Not ideal but it works.

If you need to do completely different things (so an overload for each type would be more appropriate) you will have to put the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.name.aspx) on the OperationContract like so:

```
[OperationContract(Name ="SendPayment")]
SendMessage (Payment p); 

[OperationContract(Name ="SendConfig")]
SendMessage (Config c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in to [Agatha](http://davybrion.github.com/Agatha/), it's a request/response pattern. You have a request/response for each action. On the client, you add the request to the Dispatcher and then you can ask the response, or trigger the request.