# Weird names in WCF metadata when using Generic classes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nhibernate, wcf-data-services

I am facing a very weird problem while creating a wcf data service with NHibernate 3.0

This is my concrete class which I want to expose as part of data service

```
public class PayeeType : LookupIdentifierType<int, CamConnect.Entities.DomainEntities.Lookup.PayeeType, PayeeTypeIdentifiers>
{
    public virtual String TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the base class (generic) definition

```
[IgnoreProperties("Identifier")]
public abstract class LookupIdentifierType<TId, TDto, TIdentifier>
{
    public virtual TIdentifier Identifier 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return (TIdentifier)Enum.Parse(typeof(TIdentifier), Id.ToString()); 
        } 
        //set 
        //{
        //    String idString = (Convert.ChangeType(value, value.GetTypeCode())).ToString();
        //    Id = Int32.Parse(idString) as TId; 
        //} 
        set
        {
            //String idString = (Convert.ChangeType(value, value.GetTypeCode())).ToString();
            Id = (TId)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TId));
        }
    }

    public virtual String IdentifierText
    {
        get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(TIdentifier), Identifier); }
        set 
        {
            System.Globalization.TextInfo myTI = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;                
            TIdentifier temp;                
            bool success = Enum.TryParse<TIdentifier>(value, true, out temp);
            if (!success) Enum.TryParse<TIdentifier>(myTI.ToTitleCase(value).Replace(" ",""), true, out temp); 
            Identifier = temp; 
        }
    }

    public static TReturn GetForIdentifier<TReturn>(TIdentifier identifier) where TReturn : class, ILookupIdentifierType<TIdentifier>
    {
        Type constructedType = typeof(TReturn);
        ILookupIdentifierType<TIdentifier> returnObj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType) as ILookupIdentifierType<TIdentifier>;
        returnObj.Identifier = identifier;
        return returnObj as TReturn;
    }
}
```

Now when I see the service metadata I get very weird names for my base types

```
<Schema Namespace="Entities.Entities.Lookup" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm">  
<EntityType Name="PayeeType" 
    BaseType="Entities.Entities.Lookup.LookupIdentifierType
    _x0060_3_x005B_System.Int32_x0020_.Entities.DomainEntities.Lookup.
    PayeeType_x0020.Entities.Identifiers.PayeeTypeIdentifiers_x005D_" />
```

This causes the add reference functionality to fail cause (as far as I know) WCF data service doesnt allow underscores in the name and I get 'Name' attribute is invalid error.

Has anybody encountered this before? How can I change the name of the generic base types?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the data contract name for the base class explicitly when using generics.

See
[Naming Generic DataContracts in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509803/naming-generic-datacontracts-in-wcf)